# Why does my render not show whitespot/overexposed part when i save it in OpenEXR format?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, file-format, emission

I've been wondering why this happens. When I save my rendered image (this is a smoke & fire sim) in OpenEXR format, it doesn't show any whitespot, instead it is full of a solid blue color, maybe this is good in a dynamic range sense but i can't seem to find a solution on how to return the white highlight, I tried to mess with curves and brightness in after effects without avail. But, when I use PNG format, it shows the whitespot just fine. Is there any compositing tricks/render setting to do in order to show the whitespot in the OpenEXR format?

(Rendered in Cycles)

OpenEXR:
[image: OpenEXR format]
PNG (The one in viewport also looks the same as PNG):
[image: PNG format]

Here are some settings that i use:
[image: 12345]
[image: 123456]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Blender's EXR stores the data "as is" with no color transformation. This is a format for wide data transfer, not for preview. There are things to do, but that highly depends on what softwares you use when doing your final edits.
In short, the things is that you want to set your EXR to a linear color that reproduces Blender's Filmic color management (usually via LUTs and some gamma adjustments) and set your final output to sRGB.

On Blender, it's [as on this topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/247725/53447):
Set your EXR's nodes to `Linear` color management, and your final file output to `Standard` color management.

On another topic: Be carefull with DWAA compression. If you only output your final render, it's fine. But if you ever deal with passes, don't use it, it will destroy them. Use Pxr24 if you want lossy, or any losslees compression method. But DWAA will lose crucial data on passes. Other software automatically use another compression method for passes, but not Blender.

Comment: Thank you for the help!